# Please merge [log] and [logs] into [logging]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Currently on Stack Overflow there are:

- [log](/questions/tagged/log) (720 questions)
- [logs](/questions/tagged/logs) (195 questions)
- [logging](/questions/tagged/logging) (4196 questions)

I don't have the reputation to synonimize [log](/questions/tagged/log) and [logs](/questions/tagged/logs) into [logging](/questions/tagged/logging), but I think they should be merged.

Comment: I took the liberty to suggest log and logs as synonyms to logging

Answer (score 1):

While I don't intend to stop this tag merge - as I will mention beneath, it seems logical - I would like to mention some of my thoughts on this.

At first sight this seems like a pretty straightforward and logical suggestion. If you check the questions in the first 2 tags though (*log* and *logs*) they most often handle problems that have left some message in the log(s) of system X. And the poster wants help deciphering this message that - admittedly - can be somewhat cryptic at times.

The tag *logging* on the other hand seems to be about the act of adding logging functionality to your code and using this or that logging library. At least that's the distinction that I instinctively make between the first two and the latter. And it seems to me that the distinction *lives* on SO as well.

If my point of view has any merit, there is still a merge possible between *log* and *logs*.

Comment: If that's the case then I don't see [tag:log]/[tag:logs] as very useful: they are meta-tags, as they don't make sense on their own. I think they should be burninated *if* this is the case.

Comment: It's no doubt not as black and white as I have put it here. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6481810/701884) for example would definitely contribute to your statement